# How can I set the button full width on mobile in SFMC Email Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, email-template

Is there a way to set the button on Full Width in Mobile view?

[image: Button not full width on mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a full width button in both "Desktop" and "Mobile" view. You need to apply CSS to the button code. Apply width:100% in CSS.

E.g. Following button will have 100% width in both views

```
<button type="button" class="className">Button Text</button>
<style>
.className {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```